# how to rename file before upload in php

Tags: php, image

I want to rename file dynamically and then upload it. I am fetching name of file from DB. But when I rename file it's not taking name value coming from DB. It's considering static part I am adding to it. Here is my code

uploadId.php:

```
      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","****","database");
      $result= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT op_id FROM Optrs_info WHERE op_id='1234'");
      $res= mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
      $opid= $res["op_id"];
      $id= $opid . "add2";
      $_SESSION['id']= $id;
```

And here I am uploading file with new name

```
<?php

  include("uploadId.php");
  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
  $extension = end($temp);
  $path="/var/www/tcpdf/pictures/";

 $filename=basename($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
 $filename =  $_SESSION['id'] . (string) strrchr($filename, '.');
 $filename =  $_SESSION['id'] . '.' . $extension;

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"],$path . $filename))
  {
      echo "Uploaded";
  }
?>
```

When I tried new file uploaded with add2.jpeg but $opid value is not getting added.

Comment: Do you realize that with `$filename =  $_SESSION['id'] . '.' . $extension;` line you just overwrite the current `$filename` value?

Comment: Ya I know. That is the new file name which I want.

Comment: "That is the new file name which I want" --- if it's what you want - what your question is about then?

Comment: value of $opid is not getting added with "add2"(in uploadId.php). in $_SESSION['id'] only "add2" value is coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
include("uploadId.php");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$path="/var/www/tcpdf/pictures/";

 $filename = basename($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
 $filename = $_SESSION['id'] . strrchr($filename, '.') . $extension;

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"],$path . $filename))
 {
     echo "Uploaded";
 }
?>
```